# Where to define setTrustAllPackages=true in @MessageDriven bean in external ActiveMQ

Tags: serialization, activemq-classic, payload, message-driven-bean

I am doing a Publish - Subscribe using external ActiveMQ (5.15.10). My application is deployed on TomEE 8.0.1 server and ActiveMQ configurations are done in tomee.xml.

I am able publish the message successfully but while receiving messages am facing issues. In onMessage method I need to process a pojo and I get below error

**"This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload"**

I use EclipseLink JPA in my application and I need to send the pojo that I receive in onMessage  method to my @Stateless bean (here UserService) to process it further. So, UserService is injected with @EJB annotation in my MDBSubscriber class below.

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(
                    propertyName = "destinationType", 
                    propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty( 
                    propertyName = "destination", 
                    propertyValue = "userQueue")
            
        }
    )

public class MDBSubscriber implements MessageListener {
    
    @EJB
    UserService uService; 
    
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {    
    
        if(msg instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objMsg = (ObjectMessage) msg;
            UserForm uForm=  (UserForm) objMsg.getObject();
            ----
            ----
            uService.process(uForm);
        }
     }
}
```

When I read through ActiveMQ docs, it says setTrustAllPackages=true   can be set on ActiveMQConnectionFactory object but since am using @MessageDriven Bean I don't have ActiveMQConnectionFactory object in my class defined above.

So, my problem is where or how do we define setTrustAllPackages=true in @MessageDriven Bean?

I am stuck with this problem since more than 10 days and could not find a solution.
Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this via a system property as well which avoids the trustAllPackages connection factory option.  There is [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage) for this already on the ActiveMQ site.

In case you want to shortcut this mechanism, you can allow all packages to be trusted by using * wildcard, like

```
-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*
```